# c++ lists question

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want put a value from front of the list into an another list but I am getting an error.

for exmaple

```
List<int> li;
List<int> li2;

.............
.............

li2.push_back(li.front()); // this statement doesnt work for me.
```

Can someone please help me.

example code:

```
   list<int> li;
   list<int> li2;
   li.push_back(1);
   li.push_back(2);
   li.push_back(3);

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {

    cout<<li.front()<<endl;
    li2.push_back(li.pop_front());

   }
```

Comment: "List" is not a standard list. Perhaps you want to be using std::list?

Comment: define doesn't work. Won't compile, throws an exception, does not have the element as expected?

Comment: Are you sure `li` has at least one element in it?  If it doesn't, that won't work.

Comment: its the std list. sorry for the caps.

Comment: @James li has 100 values I checked the size and both list types are int.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to match up.

Comment: `self.bank_account() += 100000000;` doesn't work, either. Why not? As mentioned previously, you seriously need to elaborate on "this statement doesnt work for me.,"  Strictly speaking, `li.push_back(li2.front())` will work, assuming: List is `std::list ` and li2 is not empty. Otherwise, POST MORE CONTEXT SO WE CAN HELP YOU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, Be aware that when the list is empty, the pop_front() and pop_back() will throw exceptions - resulting in segmentation fault. So it is mandatory to check the size of the list 
i. directly - using the list function 
ii.indirectly using the for loop as shown in the program.

### Sample Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{

    list<int> li;
    li.pop_front();

    return 0;
}
```

### Ouput

-laptop:~/Study/Pgm$ ./test
Segmentation fault

I think this is the behaviour in all OS, I use g++ (4.4.1) on Linux platform.

Comment: Calling `pop_front()` or `pop_back()` on an empty list does not result in an exception being thrown, it results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

`pop_front()` just removes the first element from the list.  It does not return the element.

You need to call `front()` to get the element at the beginning and then call `pop_front()` to remove it from the list:

```
li2.push_back(li.front());
li.pop_front();
```

Comment: yeah I got it. generally my pop returns my value. here in c++ it doesnt work

Comment: `std::list`'s `pop()` function *never* returns a value - the idea being that they didn't want the efficiency loss of a useless return when you don't want to use the return value. It's quite common - probably more common than not - for other sorts of linked list implementations to have their `pop()` return the value that you're popping, but `std::list` doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Jonathan M Davis: I think I read somewhere that the real reason that `pop()` doesn't return a value is that it is nearly impossible to write an exception-safe `pop()` that returns a value.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...at least based on what you *seem* to be trying to accomplish, it looks like list.splice is probably the right tool for the job:

```
std::list<int> li, li2;

li.push_back(1);
li.push_back(2);
li.push_back(3);

li2.splice(li2.end(), li, li.rend(), li.rbegin());
```

In fact, `splice` is one of the few good reasons to use `std::list` at all.